# Set font size on phone and tablet

Tags: android, fonts, textview, android-fonts

How to set the font size for a textview in a phone and a tablet. The posts I've referred suggested to creating `dimen.xml` and placing them in different folders namely `values-mdpi`,`values-hdpi`,`values-ldpi` . The tablet (1024x600) resolution picks from the `values-mdpi` folder and so does the the phone (320x480) also picks from the `values-mdpi` folder, this makes the font look really big and distorted on the phone, whereas it looks fine on the tablet.

Is there any way to specify a font size for the phone and tablet separately.

Comment: there are 2 ways: **1** Create diffrent layout for diffent screen size.  **2** Or simply set the size in dp/sp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For tablets I use:

- `values-sw600dp` for 7″
- `values-sw720dp` for 10″

This slution can be used not just  for localizing dimensions but also other values (for instance, styles).

Comment: Very helpful for me too.

Comment: I am a bit confused, this appears to work but in the "dimen" folders should I actually use sp or dp for the font sizes? It is not quite clear to me how it all scales...

Comment: What folder does an 8" tablet pull values from?

Answer (score 1):

It looks you got misunderstood from references. You should takes `values`, `values-large` folders for variation in fonts of Phone and Tablet. And for better results keep using `sp` units rather than dp for Font Size

Answer (score 0):

You could just use sp units instead. It is a lot simpler.

Comment: Thank you. But I forgot to mention that I've been using sp units.

Comment: Not according to your original post.

Answer (score 0):

I tryed this will work text size set default size

create :android/res/values/styles.xml

```
<style name="Widget.TextView">    
 <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall</item>    
</style>
<style name="TextAppearance.Small">  
<item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>    
<item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>    
<item name="android:textColor">?textColorSecondary</item>    
</style>
```

where

```
<item name="textColorSecondary">@android:color/secondary_text_dark</item>
```

these colors are defined in /res/color/, check /res/color/secondary_text_dark.xml